# Did Mountain Lion fix Launchpad's re-arranging curse?

Tags: launchpad

Anyone that has used Launchpad aggressively knows that (at least on Lion) it would re-arrange the icons upon reboot.  There was no way to save or lock the order and location of the icons.  Is this fixed now in Mountain Lion?  Or did they just add a search bar and call it good?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fixed.  I have been rearranging program icons for hours every day, over two days, rebooting repeatedly, on a Fall 2010 MacBook Air, and the order and orientation has stuck (stayed) every time.

As far as I can tell, this is finally fixed.

Comment: I believe it was already fixed with the 10.7.4 update.

Comment: No, the bug still exists in 10.7.4. And yes, it is finally crushed in Mountain Lion.

Comment: 10.7.5 explicitly addresses a bug where restarts re-sort the Launchpad layout.